# Center text in mulrirow and multicolumn table

Tags: multirow, multicolumn

I just dont know how to centering the text in multirow and multicolumn table. And how to put a line to te right of the table.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{txfonts} %Times New Roman
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,slovak]{babel}


\makeatletter
\begingroup
\toks0=\expandafter{\@cline{#1}-{#2}\@nil}
\@ifpackageloaded{booktabs}{%
\toks2=\expandafter{\@@@cmidrule[{#1}-{#2}]{#3}{#4}}%
 }{}
 \catcode`-=\active
  \edef\x{\gdef\unexpanded{\@cline#1-#2\@nil}{\the\toks0}}\x
\@ifpackageloaded{booktabs}{%
\edef\x{\gdef\unexpanded{\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4}{\the\toks2}}\x
}{}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
       \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline

        \multirow{2}{*}{Panda} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Tiger} \\ \cline{2-3}
                             & \multicolumn{1}{l}{aaaaaa} & \multicolumn{1}        {l}{bbbbb} \\
        \hline
        kdsjfk & kasjdf &kjadsf \\
        kdsjfk & kasjdf &kjadsf \\
        kdsjfk & kasjdf &kjadsf \\
        kdsjfk & kasjdf &kjadsf \\
\hline        
    \end{tabular}

\caption{xxx}
\label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that you looking for this:

[image]

I first remove unnecesary `\multicolumns` (see code) and than add ˙`|˙` to `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Tiger}` ...

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{txfonts} %Times New Roman
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,slovak]{babel}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\toks0=\expandafter{\@cline{#1}-{#2}\@nil}
\@ifpackageloaded{booktabs}{%
\toks2=\expandafter{\@@@cmidrule[{#1}-{#2}]{#3}{#4}}%
 }{}
 \catcode`-=\active
  \edef\x{\gdef\unexpanded{\@cline#1-#2\@nil}{\the\toks0}}\x
\@ifpackageloaded{booktabs}{%
\edef\x{\gdef\unexpanded{\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4}{\the\toks2}}\x
}{}
\endgroup
\makeatother

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
       \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Panda} 
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Tiger} \\ 
        \cline{2-3}
    &   aaaaaa & bbbbb          \\
        \hline
        kdsjfk & kasjdf &kjadsf \\
        kdsjfk & kasjdf &kjadsf \\
        kdsjfk & kasjdf &kjadsf \\
        kdsjfk & kasjdf &kjadsf \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{xxx}
\label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```